# Remover campo hidden jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte form:

```
<button type="button" id="remover<? echo $valor->int_cod; ?>" idProspect="<? echo $valor->int_cod; ?>" value="<? echo $valor->int_cod; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pequeno remover"><? echo $valor->int_nome." - ".$valor->int_whatsapp; ?></button>

<input type="hidden" class="hide" idprospect="<? echo $valor->int_cod; ?>" value="<? echo $valor->int_cod; ?>" name="prospects[]">
```

Gostaria de ao clicar em cima dele, seja removido.
Fiz da segtuinte forma:

```
$(".remover").click(function(){
    var idProspect = $(this).attr("idProspect");
    $("#remover"+idProspect).remove();
});
```

Porém, só removeu o button, o hidden não remove.
Como eu faço pra remover o hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note que quando você executa `$("#remover"+idProspect).remove();`, `remove()` se refere apenas a `$("#remover"+idProspect)`, então além disso seria necessário fazê-lo também para o input adicionando `$("input[type=hidden]").remove();` , `$(".remove").remove();`, `$(this).next().remove();` ou da forma que for mais conveniente para a sua situação.

No caso `$(".remove").remove();` remove todos os elementos com a class `remove`, `$("input[type=hidden]").remove();` remove todos os input do tipo `hidden`,  `$(this).next().remove();` remove apenas o elemento seguinte ao button clicado.

Answer (score 1):

O exemplo abaixo exclui como deseja mas teria que usar o "Class" para referir-se a mais de um elemento:

```
<input type="text" class="remover" value="value1">
<input type="text" class="remover" value="value2">
<input type="hidden" class="remover" value="value3">
<a id="removerTodos" href="#">Remover</a>
<a id="contarInput" href="#">Contar input ativos</a>


$('#removerTodos').click(function(e){
   $('.remover').remove();
});

$('#contarInput').click(function(e){
   var qtd = $('input').size();
   alert(qtd);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Aqui está uma forma mais simples de se fazer isso.
Caso não queira assim, adicione o valor $valor->int_cod na classe e não na id do elemento, porque adicionando o valor $valor->int_cod na id do elemento, você vai estar criando duas identificações iguais.

```
<button class="remove">Botão</button>
<input type="hidden" class="remove"/>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.remove').on('click', function() {
        $('.remove').remove();
    });
});
```